# Formatting in file using Fortran

Tags: fortran, format

```
   do i=1,10
    write(21,19) (dai(i,j),j=1,10)
   end do
   19 format(10f12.10)
```

This is part of my code where I input in file, here 21 is unit of my file. I want to print 10x10 matrix in file such that only 10 digits are there after decimal. The output of this is formatted matrix but with elements having no space between them. Also if I remove format line from code the file output is usual 10x10 matrix(unformatted). What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want spaces in the formatted output, you have to include them in the format. Either explicitly using the appropriate descriptors or by increasing the fields for your numbers.

E.g.,

```
 19 format(10(f12.10,1x))
```

or

```
 19 format(10f25.10)
```

Comment: If there is a duplicate, I can delete this, but a quick search mostly revealed askers having too much whitespace.

Comment: Thanks it helped me, also I have only 1 digit before decimal in every number I printed in file so why when i used 12 as my width(10 reserved for after decimal digits) I didn't got space of that remaining digit?

Comment: @Pirateking 10 decimal digits, one for the dot (decimal) so only one remains for the digit in front of the dot. All characters count. For negative numbers you also have to count with the minus sign.